# Is there a difference in how sys.path is populated when executing symlinks in Windows and Unix systems?

Tags: python, windows, unix

I have a python script in directory A which is pointed to by a symlink in another directory B.

In my python script I have this code:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

When I execute the symlink on Unix, the system path contains directory A.
When I execute the symlink on Windows, the system path contains the directory B.

Why is this the case?

Comment: In systems with `realpath`, the interpreter calls it to resolve links in the script path. The equivalent in Windows would be to open a handle for the script and call `GetFinalPathNameByHandle`. In Python 3 this is available as `os.path._getfinalpathname`. This returns an extended local-device path that starts with the "\\?\" prefix. You can remove the prefix, but "\\?\UNC\" should be replaced with "\\" (two leading backslashes) to get a valid UNC path such as "\\server\share\path".

Comment: @eryksun I'm still unsure of the code changes this would involve to make Windows behave like Unix in this case.

Comment: To get this behavior by default for all of your scripts, you could patch the interpreter's init code in a private build. To change it for everyone, you need to open an enhancement request at bugs.python.org and submit a PR on GitHub.